# Jupyter notebook kernel not connecting

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have previously used `Jupyter Notebook` (python 2 and 3) on my mac. After not using it for a while, there seems to be a problem I am unable to fix. When starting the notebook from terminal using the command `Jupyter notebook`, and then select a notebook I want to work with, I get the error:

```
"A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration."
```

I am positive this has nothing to do with my internet connection (I have tried 2 machines connected to different networks).

I have read that the browser could be the problem, therefore I have installed Chrome and Firefox. However, I get this error when I am using Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.

Then I read about it being a proxy issue. I have tried to add the server address of the notebook to the `No proxy fields` of the advanced network preferences of my mac, and of the advanced setting on Firefox.

The only thing I can think of is that I am entering the wrong server address?

I do not know much about setting and errors in general, hopefully someone can provide me with some alternative options to get Jupyter working again.

Terminal output:

```
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback <functools.partial object at 0x111e2b208>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 759, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 536, in <lambda>
    self.io_loop.add_callback(lambda : self._handle_events(self.socket, 0))
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    self.pre_handler_hook()
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 248, in pre_handler_hook
    self.saved_sigint_handler = signal(SIGINT, default_int_handler)
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
[I 19:03:26.685 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 928, in start
    raise RuntimeError("IOLoop is already running")
RuntimeError: IOLoop is already running
[I 19:03:29.696 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 928, in start
    raise RuntimeError("IOLoop is already running")
RuntimeError: IOLoop is already running
[I 19:03:32.712 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 928, in start
    raise RuntimeError("IOLoop is already running")
RuntimeError: IOLoop is already running
[W 19:03:33.717 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 2cf24420-719b-4666-ad9f-fcdf8db505f3
[E 19:03:33.721 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception in /api/kernels/2cf24420-719b-4666-ad9f-fcdf8db505f3/channels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 498, in _run_callback
        result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 262, in open
        super(ZMQChannelsHandler, self).open()
      File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/base/zmqhandlers.py", line 176, in open
        self.send_ping, self.ping_interval, io_loop=loop,
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'io_loop'
[E 19:03:34.749 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception in /api/kernels/2cf24420-719b-4666-ad9f-fcdf8db505f3/channels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 498, in _run_callback
        result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 262, in open
        super(ZMQChannelsHandler, self).open()
      File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/base/zmqhandlers.py", line 176, in open
        self.send_ping, self.ping_interval, io_loop=loop,
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'io_loop'
[I 19:03:35.724 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
[E 19:03:35.771 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception in /api/kernels/2cf24420-719b-4666-ad9f-fcdf8db505f3/channels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 498, in _run_callback
        result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 262, in open
        super(ZMQChannelsHandler, self).open()
      File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/base/zmqhandlers.py", line 176, in open
        self.send_ping, self.ping_interval, io_loop=loop,
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'io_loop'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 928, in start
    raise RuntimeError("IOLoop is already running")
RuntimeError: IOLoop is already running
[E 19:03:36.791 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception in /api/kernels/2cf24420-719b-4666-ad9f-fcdf8db505f3/channels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 498, in _run_callback
        result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 262, in open
        super(ZMQChannelsHandler, self).open()
      File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/base/zmqhandlers.py", line 176, in open
        self.send_ping, self.ping_interval, io_loop=loop,
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'io_loop'
[E 19:03:37.810 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception in /api/kernels/2cf24420-719b-4666-ad9f-fcdf8db505f3/channels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 498, in _run_callback
        result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 262, in open
        super(ZMQChannelsHandler, self).open()
      File "/Users/xxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/base/zmqhandlers.py", line 176, in open
        self.send_ping, self.ping_interval, io_loop=loop,
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'io_loop'
[W 19:03:38.733 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 19:03:38.733 NotebookApp] Kernel 2cf24420-719b-4666-ad9f-fcdf8db505f3 died, removing from map.
[W 19:03:38.830 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/2cf24420-719b-4666-ad9f-fcdf8db505f3/channels?session_id=3F75F379F865488D8379D3BB7FC0BF0F (::1): Kernel does not exist: 2cf24420-719b-4666-ad9f-fcdf8db505f3
[W 19:03:38.838 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/2cf24420-719b-4666-ad9f-fcdf8db505f3/channels?session_id=3F75F379F865488D8379D3BB7FC0BF0F (::1) 12.00ms referer=None
[W 19:03:40.859 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 2cf24420-719b-4666-ad9f-fcdf8db505f3:3F75F379F865488D8379D3BB7FC0BF0F
```

Comment: How you installed Python? are use using some distributions like anaconda?

Comment: I have used pip to install both python 3 and jupyter

Comment: Could it be firewall? my jupyter runs by default on 8888. If you had any kind of firewall installed it will probably prevents access to ports - maybe even in localhost. If that's not the case, you can always try re-installing jupyter with `pip uninstall jupyter` and then install it again.

Comment: @RockyLi, I have tried uninstalling and then installing using pip already, unfortunately it did not work. About the firewall, how could I check whether there is any kind of firewall installed? And do you suggest removing it?

Comment: @C.D Maybe checkout this link https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/199   It seems that the file in the folder are chmodded for a different user/ wrong privilege level? In that case you may need to reset the privilege levels of the file.

Comment: @RockyLi, the link indeed talks about the same issue. However, I get this error for every .ipynb file I try to open or create. So I suspect it has to do with some sort of overall privilege levels (not for a specific file), or has nothing to do with privilege levels at all

Comment: I got the same problem when the kernel hit a memory quota, and the parent jupyter process was killed. Presumably you have already confirmed that the server is still running. The client will not get notified if the server shuts down, so it will just try to reconnect.

Comment: Can you include the output from the server? What's shown in the terminal when this happens.

Comment: @C.D Is it possible that you're having wrong user/ privilege for all files? please check using `ls -l` to see both user and privilege settings. You can also monitor the terminal logs that jupyter notebook will provide you - usually if communication happens it will log it on the terminal.

Comment: @HåkenLid, I have added the terminal output to the post

Comment: Looks like it might be because you have an incompatible version of Tornado. (A python web framework that is a dependency of Jupyter). Here's a similar github issue. https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/272

Comment: Try using anaconda/miniconda to install `jupyter` (or even better `jupyterlab`).  `conda` makes life easier when dealing with package dependencies; it also includes `pip`.

Comment: @HåkenLid, the problem was indeed the version of Tornado I was running. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool. You can write an answer to your own question and accept it. It might be helpful for someone else with the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Running the following version of jupyter and tornado seemed to solve the issue:

Jupyter: 4.4.0

Tornado: 4.5.3

I needed to downgrade my version of tornado (which was 5.0.2)

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem too. My problem was because of a custom module name. I named the module 'copy.py.' My issue was solved when I renamed it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way out, **Installing Python on my PC solved it**. I didn't install python before installing anaconda

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you are about to answer an old question (this one is over 2 years old) that already has an accepted answer (that is the case here) please ask yourself: Do I really have a substantial improvement to offer? If not, please consider refraining from answering.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the kernal related issues and all my problems were solved by installing jupyter notebook from anaconda navigator.

So,The best way to handle jupyter notebook related problems is to install jupyter notebook from anaconda navigator for your environment in which you want to run jupyter notebook. If you will install jupyter notebook from anaconda navigator then you will not face any problem.

Comment: This is not correct at all, and represent a misunderstanding of what anaconda navigator really is (a simple GUI that thinly wraps over the shell operations otherwise required)/