# Cannot connect to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

My environment:

Windows 10 Professional
Python 3.7.2
virtualenv 16.4.3

I created a new virtual environment with D:\Python37\Scripts\virualenv env

Then I activated the virtual environment with env\Scripts\activate

Then I installed jupyter with pip install --upgrade jupyter

Finally, I started jupyter with jupyter notebook

Everything starts up fine, and I create a new Python 3 notebook. Unfortunately, the notebook never connects to the server. I get the following error message in powershell

Replacing stale connection: (token)

In the browser, I get the following error message:

*"A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration."*

My two prior virtual environments (with Jupyter) work fine. I've deleted .ipython, .jupyter, AppData\Roaming\jupyter, without any luck.

I've cleared cookies from my browser and have tried a different browser. Nothing works.

I've created two other virtual environments before, and both of those still work.

All jupyter notebooks in the two working environments start up as untrusted, whereas the new environment starts up as trusted. I'm guessing that I clicked on something and now the notebook is looking to start up in a trusted fashion - which may require HTTPS.

Where do I look to fix this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This appears to be a tornado issue. I found clues here.

1. [Jupyter no connection to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963043/jupyter-notebook-no-connection-to-server-because-websocket-connection-fails)
2. [Jupyter kernel not connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820353/jupyter-notebook-kernel-not-connecting)

I looked at the version of tornado (from the above links) in an environment that was working. It turns out that the version was **5.1.1**.

I looked at the version of tornado in an environment that was NOT working. It turns out that the version was **6.0**.

I downgraded the version of tornado in my non-working environment to 5.1.1 with the following command.

pip install --upgrade tornado==5.1.1

And now the non-working environment works!

Comment: I dont' get it. I have the same dependencies in two environments (notebook 6.4.6) and tornado (6.1), in one it works fine and in the other one it doens't. A mystery!

Answer (score 3):

Anaconda is pretty good at handling any dependencies.I just tried this using Anaconda in the terminal:

```
# see current envs
conda info -e

# make new environment, feel free to add your version of python with python=3.7 handle
conda create -n test

activate test

conda list   #This should appear empty
conda install jupyter  #y to install everything.

jupyter notebook  #launch jupyter notebook
```

Mine comes up as 'trusted'. The method above may not necessarily be the most minimalist way of doing things, but at least nothing breaks and you're up in running in no time. I'm using `conda version: 4.6.2`

Comment: Found the solution - latest version of tornado brought in by pip install --upgrade juypter seems to create issues with websockets. See my answer below.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! Did you try using conda to create your envs?

Comment: I did, but there is some confusion with the way that Visual Studio installs Anaconda3. I'll uninstall it and reinstall it properly. I have Visual Studio installed for some integration work. One of the issues that I had with Anaconda was the lack of control I had over environment location. Fortunately I have a lot of drive space where Anaconda3 is installed, but it's still a bit annoying.

Comment: In case you didn't find it already, I found this for you. Hope it helps It looks like you should use the --prefix tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926940/how-to-specify-new-environment-location-for-conda-create

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the situation was different. It was a browser caching issue, i.e., I would call jupyter-lab using a batch script and it would just open a tab. Closing all explicitly tabs and then the browser worked me.

If there was an old instance of another disconnected jupyter-lab, it would somehow not establish a proper connection.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is one of the top answers to a Google search on the error :

"*A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.*"

This might also have nothing to do with any install or library.
It may just be a proxy setting in your browser or on your system directly. 
One solution may be to deactivate the proxy or add an exception to Jupyter's URI.

Comment: I have no proxy configured on this system.

Comment: @MarkEggers I am well aware that your problem was a library issue, but since it was the issue I faced, linked to a proxy setting, and that this post is high ranking in the search results related to this error message, I posted the answer for posterity

Answer (score 1):

Using pip to install some packages resulted in confusing the jupyter installation. So you can uninstall the packages installed with pip, disable the jupyter_contrib_nbextensions, then try to use conda install as possible.

```
jupyter labextension disable my-extension
```

Comment: Same for me after running `!pip install --upgrade torch`, which gave: `ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
fairseq 1.0.0a0+7818f61 requires cffi, which is not installed.
fairseq 1.0.0a0+7818f61 requires hydra-core<1.1
[...]
torchvision 0.12.0 requires torch==1.11.0, but you have torch 2.1.2 which is incompatible.
torchaudio 0.9.0 requires torch==1.9.0, but you have torch 2.1.2 which is incompatible.` I should have updated all before upgrading pytorch.

Answer (score 0):

This solution work for me :

```
pip uninstall Pyzmq 
pip install Pyzmq==19.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my jupyterlab is open new tab on port 8889, http://localhost:8889
While look at the console (windows) , it also listing on 8888

```
>netstat -ano | findstr "888"
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8888         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       16072
```

So I change URL to 8888 port, it works

Answer (score 0):

For me this was an issue of loading the python environment (any python environment) because I had a locally created file that conflicted with an env file. I had named my own file 'xml.py', once I changed that all connections worked again. I figured it out by trouble shooting my pycharm debugger connection [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003028340-running-fine-but-while-debugging-getting-an-error-ModuleNotFoundError-No-module-named-xml-parsers-xml-is-not-a-package-) (see last post).