# jupyter notebook keeps CONNECTING TO KERNEL

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The Jupyter notebook keeps saying `Connecting to kernel`, which never reaches finally popping an error,

> A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue
>   trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server
>   configuration.

So the asterisk on the command line stays forever.

The strange part is, iPython on terminal works FINE.

Here are what I tried:

1. Change the browser from Chrome to Firefox
2. Change port number into something else than '8888'
3. Uninstalled the Jupyter and re-installed it

Anybody with similar issues?

Comment: Windows --> Change Proxy Settings --> Automatically Detect Settings --> "Turn-off"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similar issue. It was caused by the tornado-package and I had to downgrade it.

```
sudo pip3 uninstall tornado
sudo pip3 install tornado==5.1.1
```

See [Jupyter notebook: No connection to server because websocket connection fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963043/jupyter-notebook-no-connection-to-server-because-websocket-connection-fails)

Answer (score 0):

I have found this same issue, and identified it only happens with Chrome standard browser. Incognito Chrome or Firefox does not have the same issue of ipykernel not connecting.

For now I open jupyter in firefox using the following command from Terminal:

```
jupyter lab --browser Firefox
```

Not sure what the difference is with the browsers, but recently I have had an issue of not being able to access local files from chrome, so will look into this issue and see if that resolves it for Chrome standard browser.