# PyCharm & Jupyter Notebook - Where's the output?

Tags: python, pycharm

This is my first effort to run a Pycharm Jupyter Notebook project.

1) Create a project MyPythonProject. Done!

2) Create a new MyJupyterNotebook.  Done!

3) Enter print('hello') into the triangular cell. Press the green run button!

```
   Dialog appears saying please enter JupyterNotebook URL and Auth token)
```

4) Fair enough I go to command prompt type > Jupyter Notebook

carefully record it
        http://localhost:8888=/?token=4e209a6963b8dab232c0b03379d5321431726df7713c53e0

5) Enter it into the little black dialog box!

6) Seems to connect no error BUT, no feedback.  In fact I can put junk in the cell like #$#$$%#$#@! in the cell and still see no output at all.

So where is my output going?  I don't see this notebook after connecting to it? I don't see any results anywhere in PyCharm for executing the cell. For example I put junk in the cell and saw no output or errors anywhere in pycharm. I also put

```
print('hello world')
```

(sic) and saw no output.

I also don't see this Notebook has been loaded from PyCharm. And I wonder exactly how I would go about resetting the token if needed since the dialog just grabbed it I suppose its in project settings somewhere ... I am sure I am missing something but really thought I would see some type of output at this point when I run a cell. Any ideas what's wrong?

Update: I did load the notebook using file explorer in browser of Jupyter Notebook outside pycharm and I again see the contents of the file. But still not seeing any output in pycharm

Update:  [jupyter notebook keeps CONNECTING TO KERNEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55014554/jupyter-notebook-keeps-connecting-to-kernel)

Seems like latest tornado version is not working as answered above.

Comment: Were you able to make it work? Having the same issue here.

Answer (score 3):

There is a separate view for viewing output from cells in the top right. Just below the file tabs.[image]

Comment: Is there another way to see the output? The preview window is not very convenient.