# How to fix 'Install tornado itself to use zmq with the tornado IOLoop.' warning in Python

Tags: python, tornado, zeromq, pyzmq

I've been following this (https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/se-distributed-apps-zeromq-part2/) tutorial for setting up a ZeroMQ client/server setup which uses CurveZMQ to encrypt messages. The code works, however whenever I run either the client or the server it instructs me to `'Install tornado itself to use zmq with the tornado IOLoop.'`

I've found that the warning appears in any file with the following import statement.

```
from zmq.eventloop.zmqstream import ZMQStream
```

I've looked in the code for zmq and noticed that it uses "minitornado", which is likely the problem, but I don't know much about tornado or how to use it.

Answer (score 11):

You need to **upgrade** `pyzmq`. You can use this command to force your environment to reinstall updated version. (It worked for me!)

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyzmq
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's related to your problem. I googled about the same problem, but related to jupyter notebooks 500 internal server error, and found your question. I resolved my issue by downgrading tornado to version 5 (`sudo -H pip3 install "tornado==5"`) and everything works again. I hope you find a solution by now or my hint helps you.