# JupyterLab - Stuck at "Kernel Reconnecting" - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, kernel, jupyter-lab

After starting up JupyterLab through the CMD, it opens up and I select Python 3 Notebook, the editor opens up but it just stays stuck at "Kernel Reconnecting".

Anyone had the same issue and figured out a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Downgrading the tornado package did the job.

See here [Jupyter notebook: No connection to server because websocket connection fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963043/jupyter-notebook-no-connection-to-server-because-websocket-connection-fails)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. I spent the day fighting it and have just opened [issue #6062](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6062) on JupyterLab's git repo.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to solve the problem by upgrading jupyterlab to 0.35.3. I was already running Tornado 5.1.1. But a notebook failed to reconnect to a running kernel after merely being closed.

(ahem)

```
conda update jupyterlab
```

Others have solved similar problems (last month) by [downgrading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55011278/jupyter-lab-kernel-stays-reconnecting) Tornado to 5.1.1, or (more recently) keeping Tornado 6.0 but [upgrading](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4399) jupyter notebook to 5.7.5. Last year (on jupyter notebook 4.4.0 ) the solution was to [downgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820353/jupyter-notebook-kernel-not-connecting) to Tornado to 4.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Use docker On my own server occurs the same problem.

It's because of my Nginx config. Jupyter needs WebSocket to communicate.

this is my Nginx configure. Hope I can help.

```
server
    {
    listen 80;
    server_name jupyter.abser.top;

    chunked_transfer_encoding on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    # WebSocket support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and resolved it myself. Other resolutions here didn’t work. It boils down to package issues in the virtual Python environment. The tornado package might have resolved problems for some as that is one of the many packages that get re-installed with my resolution.

Good link for adding kernels with virtualenv.
https://queirozf.com/entries/jupyter-kernels-how-to-add-change-remove#add-virtualenv-as-python-kernel

Here’s my resolution for the kernel that will not connect from within jupyterlab.

1. Ensure you have virtualenv installed

   ```
    pip install virtualenv
   ```
2. Create virtual env (if you don’t have one already). I did have already called python373

   ```
    virtualenv python373
   ```
3. Source activate your virtualenv.

   ```
    source python373/bin/activate
   ```
4. Remove jupyterlab

   ```
    pip uninstall jupyterlab
   ```
5. Remove ipykernel

   ```
    pip uninstall ipykernel
   ```
6. Reinstall both in this order

   ```
    pip install ipykernel

    pip install jupyterlab
   ```
7. Run command to add to kernel spec list.

   ```
    ipython kernel install --name "python373" --user
   ```
8. Check to ensure it’s in the list

   ```
    jupyter kernelspec list
   ```

In my case, python373 was there.

9. Lastly, go back into your jupyterlab application, and start a notebook with your kernel. In my case, python373 was there and it worked perfectly after being broken prior.
10. Final thoughts
    If you are starting from scratch follow the first 9 steps, but no need to uninstall with steps 4 & 5.

I hope this helps!