# Jupyter can't connect to local kernel (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

For some reason, I'm unable to connect to python kernels in jupyter notebooks. This is completely mind boggling because, 2 weeks ago, I had no issues. I've been on vacations and, as such, I didn't change any configuration.

I created a virtual environment using

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
```

Then, I activated the virtual environment

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

And this is the list of python packages of the virtual environment

```
(venv)$ pip list
pip (9.0.1)
pkg-resources (0.0.0)
setuptools (39.0.1)
```

Now, I install jupyter

```
(venv) $ pip install jupyter
Collecting jupyter
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/df/0f5dd132200728a86190397e1ea87cd76244e42d39ec5e88efd25b2abd7e/jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-console (from jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/ee/6374ae8c21b7d0847f9c3722dcdfac986b8e54fa9ad9ea66e1eb6320d2b8/jupyter_console-6.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipykernel (from jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/b0/f0be5c5ab335196f5cce96e5b889a4fcf5bfe462eb0acc05cd7e2caf65eb/ipykernel-5.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting qtconsole (from jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/7a/8aefbc0ed078dec7951ac9a06dcd1869243ecd7bcbce26fa47bf5e469a8f/qtconsole-4.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nbconvert (from jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/39/1e67fea74dc9577cc49f9863fe3ec824e525d1304ab6027d95a94cd586f5/nbconvert-5.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipywidgets (from jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/9a/a008c7b1183fac9e52066d80a379b3c64eab535bd9d86cdc29a0b766fd82/ipywidgets-7.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting notebook (from jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/a6/dbdf0954d073ab2cf5421cad20334d1e4c780da37205c04522c045298f67/notebook-5.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-client (from jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/c3/3043fe9ffd140d03c9d091a056794ccdc427c56ec19b8eea74f9ea0a498f/jupyter_client-5.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pygments (from jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/e5/6d710c9cf96c31ac82657bcfb441df328b22df8564d58d0c4cd62612674c/Pygments-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipython (from jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/3b/3fcf422a99a04ee493e6a4fc3014e3c8ff484a7feed238fef68bdc285085/ipython-7.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 (from jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/a7/9b1dd14ef45345f186ef69d175bdd2491c40ab1dfa4b2b3e4352df719ed7/prompt_toolkit-2.0.9-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tornado>=4.2 (from ipykernel->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Collecting traitlets>=4.1.0 (from ipykernel->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/d6/abcb22de61d78e2fc3959c964628a5771e47e7cc60d53e9342e21ed6cc9a/traitlets-4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-core (from qtconsole->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/44/065d2d7bae7bebc06f1dd70d23c36da8c50c0f08b4236716743d706762a8/jupyter_core-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipython-genutils (from qtconsole->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/bc/9bd3b5c2b4774d5f33b2d544f1460be9df7df2fe42f352135381c347c69a/ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jinja2 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/ff/ae64bacdfc95f27a016a7bed8e8686763ba4d277a78ca76f32659220a731/Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nbformat>=4.4 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/27/9a654d2b6cc1eaa517d1c5a4405166c7f6d72f04f6e7eea41855fe808a46/nbformat-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting defusedxml (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/1c/17f3e3935a913dfe2a5ca85fa5ccbef366bfd82eb318b1f75dadbf0affca/defusedxml-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mistune>=0.8.1 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/ec/4b43dae793655b7d8a25f76119624350b4d65eb663459eb9603d7f1f0345/mistune-0.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting testpath (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/be/a4/162f9ebb6489421fe46dcca2ae420369edfee4b563c668d93cb4605d12ba/testpath-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pandocfilters>=1.4.1 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Collecting bleach (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/05/27e1466475e816d3001efb6e0a85a819be17411420494a1e602c36f8299d/bleach-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting entrypoints>=0.2.2 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/c6/44694103f8c221443ee6b0041f69e2740d89a25641e62fb4f2ee568f2f9c/entrypoints-0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0 (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/81/35789a3952afb48238289171728072d26d6e76649ddc8b3588657a2d78c1/widgetsnbextension-3.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting prometheus-client (from notebook->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Collecting pyzmq>=17 (from notebook->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/5a/8ce70c20efaf78fac2524b2f8d98b7360c997bc11a748dd233f3add7507e/pyzmq-18.0.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting Send2Trash (from notebook->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/49/46/c3dc27481d1cc57b9385aff41c474ceb7714f7935b1247194adae45db714/Send2Trash-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting terminado>=0.8.1 (from notebook->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/20/a26211a24425923d46e1213b376a6ee60dc30bcdf1b0c345e2c3769deb1c/terminado-0.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1 (from jupyter-client->jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jedi>=0.10 (from ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/2b/1f188901be099d52d7b06f4d3b7cb9f8f09692c50697b139eaf6fa2928d8/jedi-0.13.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting backcall (from ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Collecting decorator (from ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/cd/7c8240007e9716b14679bc217a1baefa4432aa30394f7e2ec40a52b1a708/decorator-4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" (from ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/e6/b5a1de8b0cc4e07ca1b305a4fcc3f9806025c1b651ea302646341222f88b/pexpect-4.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pickleshare (from ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/41/220f49aaea88bc6fa6cba8d05ecf24676326156c23b991e80b3f2fc24c77/pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter)
Collecting wcwidth (from prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/9f/526a6947247599b084ee5232e4f9190a38f398d7300d866af3ab571a5bfe/wcwidth-0.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.9.0 (from prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from jinja2->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/5f/23e0023be6bb885d00ffbefad2942bc51a620328ee910f64abe5a8d18dd1/MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 (from nbformat>=4.4->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/aa/69/df679dfbdd051568b53c38ec8152a3ab6bc533434fc7ed11ab034bf5e82f/jsonschema-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting webencodings (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/24/2a3e3df732393fed8b3ebf2ec078f05546de641fe1b667ee316ec1dcf3b7/webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ptyprocess; os_name != "nt" (from terminado>=0.8.1->notebook->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/29/605c2cc68a9992d18dada28206eeada56ea4bd07a239669da41674648b6f/ptyprocess-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting parso>=0.3.0 (from jedi>=0.10->ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/b1/522b2671cc6d134c9d3f5dfc0d02fee07cab848e908d03d2bffea78cca8f/parso-0.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyrsistent>=0.14.0 (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.4->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Collecting attrs>=17.4.0 (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.4->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/96/d828354fa2dbdf216eaa7b7de0db692f12c234f7ef888cc14980ef40d1d2/attrs-19.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: tornado, six, decorator, ipython-genutils, traitlets, jupyter-core, python-dateutil, pyzmq, jupyter-client, parso, jedi, pygments, backcall, ptyprocess, pexpect, pickleshare, wcwidth, prompt-toolkit, ipython, ipykernel, jupyter-console, qtconsole, MarkupSafe, jinja2, pyrsistent, attrs, jsonschema, nbformat, defusedxml, mistune, testpath, pandocfilters, webencodings, bleach, entrypoints, nbconvert, prometheus-client, Send2Trash, terminado, notebook, widgetsnbextension, ipywidgets, jupyter
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Send2Trash-1.5.0 attrs-19.1.0 backcall-0.1.0 bleach-3.1.0 decorator-4.3.2 defusedxml-0.5.0 entrypoints-0.3 ipykernel-5.1.0 ipython-7.3.0 ipython-genutils-0.2.0 ipywidgets-7.4.2 jedi-0.13.3 jinja2-2.10 jsonschema-3.0.1 jupyter-1.0.0 jupyter-client-5.2.4 jupyter-console-6.0.0 jupyter-core-4.4.0 mistune-0.8.4 nbconvert-5.4.1 nbformat-4.4.0 notebook-5.7.4 pandocfilters-1.4.2 parso-0.3.4 pexpect-4.6.0 pickleshare-0.7.5 prometheus-client-0.6.0 prompt-toolkit-2.0.9 ptyprocess-0.6.0 pygments-2.3.1 pyrsistent-0.14.11 python-dateutil-2.8.0 pyzmq-18.0.0 qtconsole-4.4.3 six-1.12.0 terminado-0.8.1 testpath-0.4.2 tornado-6.0.1 traitlets-4.3.2 wcwidth-0.1.7 webencodings-0.5.1 widgetsnbextension-3.4.2
```

This is the new list of python packages inside the virtual environment:

```
(venv) $ pip list
attrs (19.1.0)
backcall (0.1.0)
bleach (3.1.0)
decorator (4.3.2)
defusedxml (0.5.0)
entrypoints (0.3)
ipykernel (5.1.0)
ipython (7.3.0)
ipython-genutils (0.2.0)
ipywidgets (7.4.2)
jedi (0.13.3)
Jinja2 (2.10)
jsonschema (3.0.1)
jupyter (1.0.0)
jupyter-client (5.2.4)
jupyter-console (6.0.0)
jupyter-core (4.4.0)
MarkupSafe (1.1.1)
mistune (0.8.4)
nbconvert (5.4.1)
nbformat (4.4.0)
notebook (5.7.4)
pandocfilters (1.4.2)
parso (0.3.4)
pexpect (4.6.0)
pickleshare (0.7.5)
pip (9.0.1)
pkg-resources (0.0.0)
prometheus-client (0.6.0)
prompt-toolkit (2.0.9)
ptyprocess (0.6.0)
Pygments (2.3.1)
pyrsistent (0.14.11)
python-dateutil (2.8.0)
pyzmq (18.0.0)
qtconsole (4.4.3)
Send2Trash (1.5.0)
setuptools (39.0.1)
six (1.12.0)
terminado (0.8.1)
testpath (0.4.2)
tornado (6.0.1)
traitlets (4.3.2)
wcwidth (0.1.7)
webencodings (0.5.1)
widgetsnbextension (3.4.2)
```

Finally, I start jupyter

```
(venv) $ jupyter notebook
```

The browser opens, I create a new notebook and this happens:

[image]

This is what I have in the Firefox inspector console:

[image]

And this is what I have in the terminal:

[image]

I get the same issue in Firefox, Chromium and Chrome. Some hours ago, I was able to make it work when I wasn't using any virtual environment. But, in order to search for what might be causing this, I removed some dependencies from the system environment and now I'm getting the same result (i.e. not being able to use python kernels in jupyter).

Sorry if I'm missing something...I spent almost the entire afternoon trying to make this work and I'm completely fed up with this. I lost almost an entire day on this. I never had this issue before.

Btw, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: A few things that I see happening: Do you have multiple python installs? On my Mac I have two python installs (python2/3). Can you confirm pip3 is what is being run when you run pip? What happens when you telnet to the port from within the terminal? Do you get a return response back on port 8888?

Comment: I (FINALLY) found this: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4437

Also, related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820353/jupyter-notebook-kernel-not-connecting/52824269#52824269

Comment: @DavidO. it seems the issue was caused by a new version of tornado. Now you ask "why don't you use something like pipenv or poetry to control your dependencies versions?". I used pipenv for a long time but now I'm using poetry a lot more. I forgot to copy to maintain the same lock I had for pipenv and, to make things worst, the tornado package has a new version that messed up jupyter.