# What is the difference between <package name> and python-<package name>?

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, tornado

I want to downgrade tornado to a previous version because the new one causes an error according to the answers here: [Jupyter notebook kernel not connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820353/jupyter-notebook-kernel-not-connecting/52824269#52824269). I am on Ubuntu, in a virtual environment.

To check the current version of it, I used `pip freeze` and got this: tornado==6.0.1. When I use `apt-cache policy tornado` the output is: "Unable to locate package tornado". When I type `apt-cache policy python-tornado` the output is "python-tornado:   Installed: 4.5.3-1".

How do I proceed from here? My ultimate goal is to make the jupyter notebook run, and I need to figure out this tornado module for that. What is the difference between tornado and python-tornado? Which one I should care about?

Comment: The one is usually from `pypi` and the other is from package manager, that is a convention package builders use :)

Comment: See the guidelines for fedora https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Python/#_naming. Similarly, every distro have this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of those names is the actual package name under which it is [published to the Python Package Index (PyPI)](https://pypi.org/project/tornado/), which is the namespace that `pip` deals in.

The other is the name as set by your Ubuntu operating system, and given the version string, I am guessing that you are using [Ubuntu 18.04 *Bionic Beaver*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-tornado). Ubuntu uses a strict naming convention, where all Python packages must start with a `python-` prefix. These packages are managed and installed by your OS package manager.

How to proceed depends on your Jupyter setup. If it is installed and running from a virtualenv, then you can use the `pip` command when the virtualenv is active to alter versions there. Take into account that using `pip` should already ensure you are getting compatible versions installed; you could try to *upgrade* `jupyter` if `tornado` was upgraded independently.

If you are using the Ubuntu-managed [jupyter package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/jupyter) then there too the package manager should take care of matching versions.

However, if you you are using a virtualenv that still has access to the OS-mananged jupyter system while locally only tornado is installed, then you want to *add* jupyter to your virtualenv to mask the system version, which is too old.

Comment: Thank you. 
I proceeded with uninstalling and re-installing Jupyter. For some reason both `my_project_env/bin/pip install jupyter` and `sudo apt-get install jupyter`without the message that jupyter is already installed. That did not help. Then I downgraded tornado, that did not help neither. Then I typed in the base =outside the virtual environment) `conda install jupyter` and opened jupyter notebook. And it worked! I could open an ipynb file.
However, it still doesn't work in the virtual environment. And I don't understand why I was able to install it twice with two different commands.